# Is it possible to remove the Facebook sidebar from apps I publish?

Tags: facebook

I am interested in developing an app for Facebook, however, I am quite bothered by the sidebar on the right side of the screen. Is there a way to disable it so that users of my app won't see it? I have attached a pic to explain exactly which sidebar I am referring to:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0qvw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosting your app on facebook.com (apps.facebook.com/something) then you don't get to control the entire browser window, just the iframe which contains your app.

If you need full control of the browser, host your app off-facebook.

Comment: Could I make an app iframe that's just a redirect, and send people over to my site hosted off Facebook? If so, what's the best way to pass the credentials to the outside hosted app?

Comment: Doing that would be against policy - if you have an existing off-Facebook webapp you want to connect to Facebook's API there are options for that too. There are different features available if you host on-facebook, you can't choose both full control over the browser and use of the features which require integrating into Facebook's site